# PHP Timezone Conversion / PHP Date not displaying correct timezone

Tags: php, datetime, strtotime

The default timezone for my server and MySQL database is set to GMT.  My PHP code converts dates that are displayed to the user's local timezone (Eastern in this case):

```
$OPENED_DATE = '2013-03-20 21:05:00'
$OPENED_DATE = new DateTime($OPENED_DATE);
$OPENED_DATE->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
```

Then I output the date for the user:

```
$OPENED_DATE = strtotime($OPENED_DATE->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));      
$OPENED_DATE = date('F j, Y g:i A T', $OPENED_DATE);
```

Output of $OPENED_DATE: March 20, 2013 5:05PM GMT

The actual time is displayed correctly but the 'T' in the date output is still displaying GMT.  Is there a way to make it display the timezone we've converted to and not the default of GMT.  The only way I know to do this is to use `date_default_timezone_set` every time to switch to the user's timezone then switch back to GMT.  But I feel like there has to be a more efficient way...

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you outputting the date in a format, only to turn around with strtotime and do the same thing again? Just use it once `$OPENED_DATE->format('F j, Y g:i A T')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two lines are redundant

```
$OPENED_DATE = strtotime($OPENED_DATE->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));      
$OPENED_DATE = date('F j, Y g:i A T', $OPENED_DATE);
```

It is the call to `date()` which is outputting the wrong timezone.

Why not try just:

```
$OPENED_DATE = $OPENED_DATE->format('F j, Y g:i A T');
```

The `DateTime` object has the timezone set in it, but once you convert it to a timestamp and use `date()`, the server timezone is used for that time.  I think just using the DateTime object for formatting the date is sufficient to do what you want.

Comment: Makes perfect sense and worked like a charm - thank you!  Have to wait 10 minutes but will mark this as the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Since you applied the timezone setting only to your `$OPENED_DATE` variable, the `strtotime()` and `date()` functions do not receive the same timezone information.

You are passing only the year/month/day/hour/minute/section from your `$OPENED_DATE` to `strtotime()`, so there is no way for it to get the timezone information.

Now, what you *could* do is set the default timezone used for functions like `strtotime()` and `date()` as well, using `date_default_timezone_set()`.

However, this is still cumbersome and you don't need to, since already have a DateTime object and you may as well continue to use that.

DateTime objects will let you output a formatted time directly:

```
$OPENED_DATE->format('F j, Y g:i A T');
```

Thus skipping the `strtotime()` and `date()` step entirely.